# onclick event on Ajax output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i am using Ajax to get a SELECT tag. I mean, if i click on a button it will generate a SELECT tag inside HTML, i have different outputs for different options of select.

I need an onclick event on that SELECT tag, i tried using JQuery

```
$('#id').click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

Its not working. Can anybody help, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the select tag is dynamically added to the HTML *after* the event was set, the event is not set on the select tag.

A simple solution is to use `live()` here:

```
$('#id').live('click', function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

as you are dynically generating html use live instead of click

```
  $('#id').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

- you have jQuery script file is inserted in your html page,
- you have assigned `id` id to one and only one item on your page,
- you give us a link to see your page if nothing else helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

`live` is now deprecated. Use `on` instead.